# How do I separate Google Analytics stats between public/private parts of web service?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm building SaaS and website is separated into public part (landing page, documentation, faq, etc) and private part (SaaS administration panel itself). I wan't to separate my stats between public part and private yet preserving ability to track users among them (i.e. conversion rates).

How can I 'tag' my pages so that I can see separate stats on my Google Analytics page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get separate stats in Google analytics by creating a [custom Segment](https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/analytics/features/advanced-segments.html).   I have an example of one I have created for the company I work for.

The intranet pages all start with intranet.(sitename)  Under advanced conditions I created a filter on page starts with intranet.(site name).    So you can figure out how to separate the pages, you could create a custom segment.

[image]

You could also create two different views(profiles) and set each up to filter the different information.  But then you would not be able to analyses them together again as they data is removed from the view by the filter.  Personally I don't like to filter views because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use profiles/views (campaign sources etc. will be kept intact even if you filter out the public parts of your website). But what might work even better for you is [content groupings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167) which would allow you to tag parts of the site as private or public and would also allow to add more granularity as needed.

Content groupings can be assigned either via additions to the tracking code or rule-based in the admin interface.

However content groupings will not allow you to assign different permissions for access to the data (as a view based solution would).